# How to get the Etheruem contract init code hash by using remix.ethereum.org?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens

How to get the Etheruem contract  init code hash by using remix.ethereum.org ?

It's a little fuzzy with bytecode and deployedBytecode, I use the contract code deploy on mainnet by others, I try to test to get the init code hash, but it got different with others people deployed.

How to get the right init code hash ?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello and welcome! I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Could you fill in some details about what happened, and also about exactly what you're looking for? (For example, is the "init code hash" you mention the transaction hash of the tx for deploying the contract?) Thanks!

Comment: I think he's asking for the Keccak256 hashed init code of the contract

Answer (score 5):

You should get the init code of the contract first, then use Keccak256 to hash it.

**1. get the init code**

Compile the contract at remix.ethereum.org and click the Bytecode button at bottom right to copy the content.

[image]

The format of the content will be like this:

```
{
    "linkReferences": {},
    "object": "***THINGS YOU NEEDED HERE***",
    "opcodes": "-",
    "sourceMap": "-"
}
```

the value of field: 'object' is the init code.

**2. keccak256 hash**

Go to https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html, paste in the content, and make sure you select Input Type as Hex, then you will get the init code hash.

[image: keccak]